# no UPI app available error with intent on samsung device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, upi, samsung

With the help of the below code. I'm able to open chooser with related application on couple of devices. I have problem with newly purchase samsung device A15 5G.

```
int GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "xxxx@okbank")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "TestUser")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "0000")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "TXN000001")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "10.10")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .build();

Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");
chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);


if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())) {
    startActivityForResult(call, chooser, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
} else {
    Toast.makeText((Activity)getContext(),"No UPI app found, please install one to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```